# Sort the top ten results

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I am getting a list in which I am saving the results in the following way

```
City Percentage
Mumbai  98.30
London 23.23
Agra    12.22
.....
```

List structure is [["Mumbai",98.30],["London",23.23]..]

I am saving this records in form of a list.I need the list to be sort top_ten records.Even if I get cities also, it would be fine.

I am  trying to use the following logic, but it fails for to provide accurate data

```
if (condition):
    if b not in top_ten:
        top_ten.append(b)   
        top_ten.remove(tmp)
```

Any other solution,approach is also welcome.

**EDIT 1**

```
for a in sc_percentage:
            print a
```

List I am getting

```
(<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLC>, 100.0)
(<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLE>, 75.0)
(<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLN>, 90.909090909090907)
(<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLS>, 83.333333333333343)
(<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLW>, 92.307692307692307)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Django?

Comment: Are you looping through your list while removing items? Because that's never a good idea...

Comment: What is the list structure ?? Is it like [[Mumbai,98.30],[London,23.33]..] ?

Comment: The logic works in java, I am beginner in django, so probably I am following a wrong approach

Comment: By list do you mean queryset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the list first and then slice it:

```
>>> lis = [['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23], ['Agra', 12.22]]
>>> print sorted(lis, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10] #[:10] returns first ten items
[['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23], ['Agra', 12.22]]
```

To get data in list form from that file use this:

```
with open('abc') as f:
    next(f)  #skip header 
    lis = [[city,float(val)]  for city, val in( line.split() for line in f)]
    print lis 
    #[['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23], ['Agra', 12.22]]
```

**Update:**

```
new_lis = sorted(sc_percentage, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10]
for item in new_lis:
   print item
```

`sorted` returns a new sorted list, as we need to sort the list based on the second item of each element so we used the `key` parameter.

`key = lambda x : x[1]` means use the value on the index 1(i.e 100.0, 75.0 etc) of each item for comparison.

`reverse= True` is used for reverse sorting.

Comment: I am using eclipse. The code is not working .
`sorted(sc_percentage, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10]`

Comment: @onkar Please post `sc_percentage` in question body.

Comment: I am unable to get revised list

Comment: @onkar and what does `type(sc_percentage)` prints?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did not get any error, I am unable to see the list. Also please check the edit

Comment: @onkar I've updated my answer, let me know if it works then I'll add some explanation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : I was able to visualize the .gif image you mentioned in your profile when your answer got downvoted . :D

Comment: @TusharMakkar Yes it sucks when someone downvotes for no valid reason.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary dont worry you have no downvotes for dis answer anymore ;)

Answer (score 8):

If the list is fairly short then as others have suggested you can sort it and slice it. If the list is very large then you may be better using `heapq.nlargest()`:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> lis = [['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23], ['Agra', 12.22]]
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, lis, key=lambda x:x[1])
[['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23]]
```

The difference is that nlargest only makes a single pass through the list and in fact if you are reading from a file or other generated source need not all be in memory at the same time.

You might also be interested to look at the source for `nlargest()` as it works in much the same way that you were trying to solve the problem: it keeps only the desired number of elements in a data structure known as a heap and each new value is pushed into the heap then the smallest value is popped from the heap.

*Edit to show comparative timing*:

```
>>> import random
>>> records = []
>>> for i in range(100000):
    value = random.random() * 100
    records.append(('city {:2.4f}'.format(value), value))


>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(10, records, key=lambda x:x[1])
[('city 99.9995', 99.99948904248298), ('city 99.9974', 99.99738898315216), ('city 99.9964', 99.99642759230214), ('city 99.9935', 99.99345173704319), ('city 99.9916', 99.99162694442714), ('city 99.9908', 99.99075084123544), ('city 99.9887', 99.98865134685201), ('city 99.9879', 99.98792632193258), ('city 99.9872', 99.98724339718686), ('city 99.9854', 99.98540548350132)]
>>> timeit.timeit('sorted(records, key=lambda x:x[1])[:10]', setup='from __main__ import records', number=10)
1.388942152229788
>>> timeit.timeit('heapq.nlargest(10, records, key=lambda x:x[1])', setup='import heapq;from __main__ import records', number=10)
0.5476185073315492
```

On my system getting the top 10 from 100 records is fastest by sorting and slicing, but with 1,000 or more records it is faster to use nlargest.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your input into something Python can handle easily:

```
with open('input.txt') as inputFile:
    lines = inputFile.readLines()
records = [ line.split() for line in lines ]
records = [ float(percentage), city for city, percentage in records ]
```

Now the `records` contain a list of the entries like this:

```
[ [ 98.3, 'Mumbai' ], [ 23.23, 'London' ], [ 12.22, Agra ] ]
```

You can sort that list in-place:

```
records.sort()
```

You can print the top ten by slicing:

```
print records[0:10]
```

If you have a huge list (e. g. millions of entries) and just want the top ten of these in a sorted way, there are better ways than sorting the whole list (which would be a waste of time then).

Comment: The list is calculated locally it self. Please can you simplify the code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For printing the top 10 cities you can use :

Sort the list first and then slice it:

```
>>> lis = [['Mumbai', 98.3], ['London', 23.23], ['Agra', 12.22]]
>>> [k[0] for k in sorted(lis, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10]]
    ['Mumbai', 'London', 'Agra']
```

For the given list

```
 >>>: lis=[("<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLC>", 100.0),("<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLW>", 92.307692307692307),("<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLE>", 75.0),("<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLN>", 90.909090909090907),("<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLS>", 83.333333333333343)]

 >>>:t=[k[0] for k in sorted(lis, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10]]
 >>>:print t
['<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLC>',
'<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLW>',
'<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLN>',
'<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLS>',
'<ServiceCenter: DELHI-DLE>']
```

Sorted function returns the sorted list with key as the compare function .

Comment: Hey I am using eclipse environment and a newbie in python development. Please can you modify the code and make it more simpler. Thank you for understanding

Comment: Can you please show me the output of the list instead of printing the individual elements ? That is use `print sc_percentage `  instead of printing using for loop .

Comment: @onkar You need to add `print "new list"` explicitly to get the output