# How do I sort records in descending order based on a extracted numerical value from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
I have a data set like this:
```

[image]

```
 Surface Book 2 Review: How Microsoft Won My Five Stars At The Edinburgh Fringe | 0.5047957
 Remove the Power PC Care 2018 PUP | 0.44716716
 9 Months of Xbox Live (New or Returning Only, otherwise 7 months for $21) $23 | 0.42284298
 US probe into Microsoft software sales in Hungary | 0.42226338
```

I am trying to sort the data based on the values which exists after `|` symbol. So basically I would like to display the whole string based on which ever has highest value and get top 10.

```
 I tried doing this but I cannot figure out how to order by only that numerical value. 

 listnew = sorted(Calculatedvalues, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)[:10]
 for item in listnew:
                 print (item)
```

My output is like this:

```
３８ What is Thinking？ #Intelligence | 0.15786803
３８ What is Thinking？ #Intelligence | 0.15786803
８．３１ PF | 0.02431465
️ Hop on, Jerry. Here are 50 points. | 0.25864878
```

If we see the score these are basically lower from what exists in a data set, I understand this is not the right way, and I was not able to find a way to order based on just specific part.

I referred to answers provided in these questions, but it did not help.

[Sort the top ten results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295060/sort-the-top-ten-results)

from one of the answers provided below: I tried using this approach mentioned

```
Calculatedvalues.sort(key = lambda x: x.split("(")[1]))
```

but I am receiving this error

```
list index out of range
```

[Sort list of strings by a part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431052/sort-list-of-strings-by-a-part-of-the-string)

Comment: is you dataset in a file?

Comment: No, I had to combine the records from file and the score to get that data set, it is more like concatenated field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you never actually split your line on `|`, you need to use `split` to convert each line into list and then sort it based on the 2nd item of the list,

Please try this,

```
listnew = sorted(Calculatedvalues, key = lambda x: float(x.split("|")[-1]), reverse=True)[:10]
# output,
# ['Surface Book 2 Review: How Microsoft Won My Five Stars At The Edinburgh Fringe | 0.5047957\n', 'Remove the Power PC Care 2018 PUP | 0.44716716\n', '9 Months of Xbox Live (New or Returning Only, otherwise 7 months for $21) $23 | 0.42284298\n', 'US probe into Microsoft software sales in Hungary | 0.42226338']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list would be correct if you split by `'|'` and then converted to `float`

```
listnew = sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: float(x.split('|')[1]))
```

Comment: `float()` doesn't care about spaces.